# Textract results format differences (interactive vs. Python script)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I am sending a PDF document to Textract using the AWS web page and through a Python script.  The resulting JSON is encoded differently using the two mechanisms.  For example, the user interface returns a JSON file with double quotes as string delimiters where the Python script uses single quotes.

Is there any control over the response from the Python script so that it matches the Textract user interface?

Using the Textract web page through the AWS console, I submitted PDF file and compared the resulting analysis JSON file with get_document_analysis() calls from my Python script.